# Unable to dispatch state values from redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react and redux and trying to dispatch states from store but unable to do so,
Please anyone help me to resolve the problem...

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import store from './reduxStore/store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';


function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Provider store={store}>
         <Sidebar ></Sidebar>
      </Provider>
    </div>
  );
}



export default (App);
```

This is my **sidebar.js** Component

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { updatePageLinkActions } from "../../reduxStore/actions/updatePageLinkActions";
import { connect } from "react-redux";



const Sidebar = () =>{

useEffect(() => {
    return updatePageLinkActions
}, [])


    return (
        <>
            <ListItem button onClick={updatePageLinkActions}>
                <ListItemIcon><Home></Home></ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
            </ListItem>
            <ListItem button onClick={() => handleOpenPage("contact")}>
                <ListItemIcon><AcUnit></AcUnit></ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary="Contact" />
            </ListItem>
        </>
        
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    updatePage: state.updatePage.pgLink
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { updatePageLinkActions })(SidebarItems);
```

Store  **Store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers';

const initialState = {};
const middleWare = [thunk]

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer, 
  initialState, 
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleWare),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
  )
) 

export default store;
```

Root Reducer  **rootReducer.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import updatePageLinkReducer from './updatePageLinRreducer';

export default combineReducers({
    updatePage: updatePageLinkReducer
});
```

Action **updatePageLinkActions.js**

```
import { UPDATE_PAGE_LINK } from "../actionTypes";
//import store from "../store";

export const updatePageLinkActions = dispatch => {

  console.log("actions log ", dispatch.payload)

  return dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PAGE_LINK,
      payload: {pageLink : "Action_pageLink" }
    })        
};
```

Reducer **updatePageLinkReducer.js**

```
import { UPDATE_PAGE_LINK } from '../actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  pgLink: []
};

// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-anonymous-default-export
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_PAGE_LINK:
      console.log("Action called ")
      return { ...state, pgLink: action.payload }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I am unable to dispatch values from store,
**Please** somebody help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using functional components I strongly recommend getting rid of using `connect`.

To get state from Redux store, you can use `useSelector` hook, and to dispatch an action, you can use `useDispatch` hook.

```js
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
...
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const updatePage = useSelector(state => state.updatePage.pgLink)

const updatePageLinkActions = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PAGE_LINK,
      payload: {pageLink : "Action_pageLink" }
    })
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your action creator is not defined properly.

It should be this:

```js
export const updatePageLinkActions = () => dispatch => {

  console.log("actions log ", dispatch.payload)

  return dispatch({
      type: UPDATE_PAGE_LINK,
      payload: {pageLink : "Action_pageLink" }
    })        
};
```